# Ad framework for Cocoa (Mac) applications?

Tags: cocoa, macos, frameworks

Does anyone know any good frameworks that would allow me to integrate some ads into my Cocoa Mac application?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Cocoa apps seem to use/like [The Deck](http://decknetwork.net/)

Comment: "Sites and apps are added to the network by invitation only ..."

Comment: Yeah.. that seems silly. Pity.